# Android TCP networking: AsyncTask vs. IntentService

Tags: android, networking, tcp, android-asynctask, android-intentservice

I’m building an Android app that needs to communicate with a server over TCP sockets. I know that networking should be done off the UI thread but I’m not sure which “threading approach” to go with: an IntentService or AsyncTask. I read that the you should use services if you have to run something continually in the background, and use AsyncTask for one-off tasks but I find this rather vague. For my application I only need to communicate with the server on startup and when a user clicks some button, which would seem to favour AsyncTask (since this seems like a one-off task). What would be the benefit and downside of using AsyncTask over an IntentService?

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't use async task, because async tasks runs in serial execution. So it will slow down your application if user go back or press multiple times. You can use a thread with handler or can use event bus library. Or for network task can use volly.